# Error "Use of undeclared type" in Xcode won't go away

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode8

I moved a Swift class declaration from one file to another and now Xcode 8.2.1 keeps nagging me with red errors "Use of undeclared type" wherever I use this class. The project does compile & run without errors, but when I edit the code the error messages pop up again.

I already

- cleaned the project
- cleaned the build folder
- deleted DerivedData manually
- restarted Xcode
- restarted my Mac

Is there anything else I can do to get rid of these messages?

Comment: Is the new file included in the same targets as the old file?

Comment: @MikeTaverne That's it! I didn't include the new file in my test target but the old file was included. Now I added it to the test target too and the messages are gone. Thanks! That was driving me crazy...

Comment: I get the same darn error.  I believe it started when I made a change to my model file and removed a field.  As noted above, the error does not prevent running etc, but it's annoying.  Hope Apple sees this. :)

Comment: I fixed a similar problem when class was in a framework. It compiled fine and the error would temporarily go away even though the framework wasn't added to the target. Once I added it to the target, it didn't appear again.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Since it's a resolved issue, it would be great for future references to have an official answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to include the new file that you moved your class to  in your test target.